# How to create table in every Apache ignite cache using JAVA SQL statement?

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I am able to create ignite cache using below code in java:

```
    Ignition.setClientMode(true);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add("127.0.0.1:48500..48520");

    discoveryMulticastIpFinder.setAddresses(set);

    TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    discoverySpi.setIpFinder(discoveryMulticastIpFinder);

    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
    cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>(CACHENAME);
    cacheConfiguration.setName(CACHENAME);
    cacheConfiguration.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");
    cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration).withKeepBinary();

    System.out.println("All Available Cache on server : "+ignite.cacheNames());
```

`ignite.cacheNames()` is printing all my created caches in the console. Now I want to create table like `MYTABLE` in each cache.

I have tried :

```
cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE( TAG VARCHAR,TIMECREATED TIMESTAMP,VALUE DOUBLE, PRIMARY KEY(TAG,TIMECREATED) )"));
```

but this query creates only one table for all caches. I cannot write query something like one below for above scenario .

```
SELECT * FROM "CACHENAME".MYTABLE WHERE SOME_CONDITION = 1;
```

I have referred [1]:[Apache Ignite : How to list all tables and all Caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049782/apache-ignite-how-to-list-all-tables-and-all-caches) question from stackoverflow but this seems to be not helping much to answer my question.

```
 Collection<QueryEntity> entities = cacheConfiguration.getQueryEntities();
 System.out.println("All available tables in "+CACHENAME+"cache : "+entities);
```

Using above code I can see cache name but no table is created inside of that cache.

Ultimately, I want to create one table `MYTABLE` in each and every cache and I should be able to query using `JAVA SQL_QUERY` method in ignite:

```
 SELECT * FROM "CACHE_NAME".MYTABLE WHERE SOME_CONDITION = 1;
```

Your answers are really valued and appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a table per cache, you should define them using [CacheConfiguration#indexedTypes](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setIndexedTypes-java.lang.Class...-) or [CacheConfiguration#queryEntities](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setQueryEntities-java.util.Collection-) properties.

This way you will have the following tables created: `"cacheName".TypeName`.

You can change name of the tables by changing the [QueryEntity#tableName](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/QueryEntity.html#setTableName-java.lang.String-) property.

Refer to the following documentation page for more information: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

You can have several tables use the same cache in Apache Ignite (discriminated on the value type) but you can't have one table that uses more than one cache for keeping its data. So the mapping of caches to tables is one-to-many.

Another answer is that `CREATE TABLE` always creates table in `PUBLIC` schema. In a schema you can't have more than one table named `MYTABLE`. You could `CREATE TABLE` to create a cache with a given name, by specifying [`CACHE_NAME`](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table#section-parameters) hint. But you can still only create one `MYTABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the cache name in the table creation SQL query.
CACHE_NAME=

Syntax:
CREATE TABLE employee (
name varchar,
phone varchar)
WITH "template=partitioned, backups=1, affinityKey=CountryCode, CACHE_NAME=risk;